# Python Extract every sentence that contains Parenthesis

Tags: regex, file-io

```
with open(searchfile) as f:

pattern = "\.?(?P<sentence>.*?\(([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\).*?)\."
for line in f:
    match = re.search(pattern, line)
    if match != None:
        print match.group("sentence")
```

I am trying to extract every sentence that contains an acronym in parenthesis (essentially 2-4 letter all caps in parenthesis.

In: Here is an (ABC) example. Do not include this sentence. Include this (AB) one. And (AVCD) this one.

Out: Here is an (ABC) example. Include this (AB) one. And (AVCD) this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
[^.]*?\([A-Z]{2,4}\)[^.]*\.
```

But note that it is a particulary inefficient way, since the pattern starts with a very permissive subpattern. You can correct that a little by adding a kind of anchor at the begining:

```
(?:(?<=.)|^)[^.]*?\([A-Z]{2,4}\)[^.]*\.
```

Unfortunatly, even with this anchor, the regex engine must check the two alternatives for the most of the characters of the string.

A better approach might be to find substrings starting with the acronym until the end of the sentence and dots, and then to extract substrings using the end offset of each results:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

txt = 'Here is an (ABC) example. Do not include this sentence. Include this (AB) one. And (AVCD) this one.'

pattern = re.compile(r'([!.?])(?=\s)|\([A-Z]{2,4}\)[^.]*(?:\.|$)')
offset = 0
result = ''
for m in pattern.finditer(txt):
    if (m.group(1)==None):
        result += txt[offset:m.end()]
    offset = m.end()

print result
```

Note: you can be sure that a dot stands for the end of a sentence, it can be something else.

Comment: How would I do this but read in the data from a text file and not a a string? My implementation of looping through a line at a time only returns the first line.

Comment: @mrobillard: You can do it easily. All you need is to store in a variable, say `subeol`, the end of the line (from `offset` to end) after the for loop (outside). Inside the for loop `result` is now: `result += subeol + txt[offset:m.end()]`, and after the if statement, you must initialize `subeol` to an empty string. You only need to put all in your line by line loop.

Comment: @mrobillard: ps: no need to put the pattern definition in the loop and you must initialize `subeol` to an empty string before your line by line loop.

Answer (score 0):

a little more efficient pattern

```
([^.(]++\([^.)]++\)[^.)]++\.)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vQ2xO4)